# i need an SQL query to alter the output result

Tags: mysql, sql, alter

I want to alter the data on output

```
--------------------------------------

| Name       | Phone      | Address  |

--------------------------------------

| Suwaid 068 | 7658945621 | 23/2 Myf |

| Akbar  0525 | 7658945621 | 23/2 Ngh |

| Shah   02513 | 7658945621 | 23/2 gju |

--------------------------------------
```

in output i want to see the name as **Suwaid, Akbar, Shah**

What sql query should i use...
My query `Select Name, Phone from Table1 ________`

Comment: You need to more clearly define your output and tell us what you have tried so far

Comment: so its always the same pattern meaning name then a space then a number or for some names there may not be any number ?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `substring_index()` for this purpose.  It is a very handy function for extracting values from delimited strings:

```
select substring_index(name, ' ', 1) as name, address
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

So Name contains two data actually, a name and a number, which is something one would avoid in a database. However, what you are looking for is string functions to get the part before the blank, i.e. the name:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING( 1, INSTR(CONCAT(name, ' ') , ' ') - 1 as PureName,
  phone,
  address
FROM table1;
```

I used CONCAT to add a blank for the case that Name really contains a name only, so INSTR would fail otherwise.

Comment: How about `Foo Bar 123` ?

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty: Well spotted. Yes, you are right. One would need more information on how to tell the name from the unwanted rest to build the perfect query.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it would require the query to be as follows:

1. To Get Names and eliminate numbers:

   ```
   with table1 as
   (
    select 'Suwaid 068' name, 7658945621 Phone, '23/2 Myf' Address from dual union 
    select 'Akbar  0525' name, 7658945621 Phone, '23/2 Myf' Address from dual union
    select 'Foo Bar 123' name, 7658945621 Phone, '23/2 Myf' Address from dual 
   )
   SELECT rtrim(name, '0123456789/') as Name,Phone, Address  FROM Table1 
   order by Name;
   ```
2. To Get only first Name:

   ```
   SELECT NVL(substr(Name, 1, instr(Name,' ')), Name) as Name,Phone, Address  FROM Table1 
   order by Name;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to replace all Numbers even if you have `Foo Bar 123 bar` it will give you the pure name. `Foo Bar bar`

```
   SELECT
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Name,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0','') as PureName,
 phone,
 address
FROM table1;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51648/1)

Comment: Oh My God!! No Comments!!

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `SUBSTRING` and `LOCATE` function to get the same like below (Assuming that the pattern is `string + space + numbers` per your post)

```
select substring(Name,1,locate(' ',Name)),
Phone from Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the result with what you all suggested.

`Select NVL(substr(name,1,instr(name,' ')),name) as PureName,phone from table1`